# Google sheets: filter columns if rows are not blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula to show all the projects for which there are hours assigned. From a first query I get the following output, listing projects and assigned hours:
[image: Intermediary output]

Now I want to filter for projects with assigned hours. Since I want to add this to my existing query, I cannot use A1 notation. Any idea? :)
[image: Goal]

Comment: Can you mind sharing what's your first query is?

Comment: what do you mean by `cannot use A1 notation`? why is that? and what is your current query.

Comment: From your question it is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, please try to be more explicit in what you are trying to achieve. Also, it would be helpful if you could share a sanitized copy of your spreadsheet and review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post, before updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=unique(query(arrayformula(split(flatten((A1:C1&"~"&A2:C)),"~")),"select Col1 where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
transpose({transpose({A1:C1}),query(transpose(query({A2:C},"select "&textjoin(",",1,index("sum(Col"&sequence(1, 3,1)&")"))&"), "select Col1 where Col2 >0")})
```

I solved the issue with this formula. But yours also worked @Mike Steelson -thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can do that:

```
=flatten(filter(A1:C1,trim(query(A2:C,,9^9))<>""))
```

[image]